# IP swapping in Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, scylla

We have healthy running 3 nodes cassandra cluster but we need to swap all 3 nodes IP address due to some issue.

So basically, we want to swap old cassandra server IP address from to new cassandra server IP address. 
My question is :-

1) Is there any specific procedure we need to follow to avoid any issue?

2) Or Just modify rpc_address, listen_address, seeds, peers table etc. and start the cassandra nodes?

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have already identified most of the steps to take. Also, ensure to follow the steps one node at a time:

1. in `cassandra.yaml` update rpc_address, listen_address, seeds, and any reference to the previous IP address. Also, ensure that `auto_bootstrap` is set to false (by default the directive is omitted and the default value is true).
2. Depending on your installation, also look in `cassandra-topology.properties` and `cassandra-rackdc.properties`
3. Stop the cassandra service
4. Change the IP address of the box (i.e. ifconfig, add the new route, etc.)
5. in `cassandra-env.sh` include the following directive with the previous IP address:
   `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.replace_address=previous_ip_address`
6. Start the Cassandra service in the node. Wait until `nodetool status` reports it as `UN`, you should notice that the new IP address is reported
7. If you added the `auto_bootstrap` directive in `cassandra.yml`, remove it\
8. remove the `cassandra.replace_address` directive from `cassandra-env.sh`
9. repeat in a different node

Comment: Thanks @Carlos but it seems you are talking about node replacement if I am not wrong. My question is nodes are same just change the IP address of them.  As per your point 1. Any reference of previous IP address. How can we identify ?

Comment: Actually, the process is similar to a replacement of a node that goes offline. I just edited the answer with the information of when the change of the IP address should occur

Comment: But previous IP address not exist now then how we can refer in cassandra-env.sh?

Comment: the change of IP addresses already occur? is the cluster running? are you having any errors?

Comment: Not changed yet. We are planning to assign new ip addresses in my up and running cassandra nodes. that's why I am asking the correct procedure. if we will assign a new IP address then old will not exist? then how we can refer? Hope, you understand my concern.

Comment: The edited response includes when the change of IP addresses should occur. Any change should be thoroughly tested before impacting any production environment. If you are using the cloud (AWS, GCP, Azure) would be to create a backup of your cluster, restore that backup in different instances, and try the change without risking your production cluster. If you are not on the cloud, one option is to create a separate cluster with commodity hardware, and try the procedure.

Comment: Thanks but still my question is unanswered. please see my comment part. you are saying about replacement procedure but I am asking about IP swapping except IP nothing change.

Comment: For the cluster point of view, you are replacing a node. The cluster needs to know that the tokens that were assigned to the node `x`, which can be found with the IP address 1.2.3.4 will be now served by the same node `x` that has the IP address 2.3.4.5

Comment: Token is associated with IP address?  Is it true?

Comment: Tokens are owned by the nodes; the distribution of that ownership depends on the topology of the cluster, the number of virtual nodes (vnodes), and replication factor. How the node is identified in the cluster, will depend on how the `broadcast_address` is set up in the cassandra.yaml file, which if not specified, will use as default value what is specified as `listen_address`.  In both cases, you can specify an IP address or a hostname (https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configGossipSettings.html) If you have specified a hostname, no action will be ...

Comment: ... needed, inferring from the question an IP address was defined, the use of  `cassandra.replace_address` will make it cleaner the transition of the ownership.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per the link you provided.listen and broadcast address for connection to the nodes and client.  i.e I have copied all the token ranges from my existing cluster(3 nodes)and put on new cluster (3 nodes)on each yaml file one by one. then copied the sstable on new cluster and restated the cluster. new cluster is up with the same data and working fine. so what I understand from my testing that there was no any IP reference in token ranges.

Comment: Above explanation is not related with current question just for understanding I have mentioned. please let me know if